# Ruby, equally distribute elements and interleave/merge multiple arrays

Tags: ruby, arrays, merge, distribute

I have multiple arrays with unknown element count like

```ruby
a = []
a << [:a, :c, :e]
a << [:b, :f, :g, :h, :i, :j]
a << [:d]
```

result should be something like ~ (I don't really care details due rounding etc)

```
r = [:b, :a, :f, :g, :d, :c, :h, :i, :e, :j]
```

#### This is how I think it could be done

First we need to expand/distribute **equally** elements in each array to same length, so we get something like

```
a << [nil, :a, nil, :c, nil, :e]
a << [:b, :f, :g, :h, :i, :j]
a << [nil, nil, :d, nil, nil]
```

Next we **interleave** them as typically would do

```
r = a.shift
a.each { |e| r = r.zip(e) }
r = r.flatten.compact
```

My current problem is how to equally (as much as it's possible) distribute those elements across array? There could be one array with 4 elements and other with 5, but probably biggest should go first.

Of course would be nice to see if there's any other way to achieve this :)

Comment: Your question doesn't really make sense. Why `[nil, :a, nil, :c, nil, :e]` instead of `[:a, :c, :e, nil, nil]`?

Comment: because need distribute elements equally (so that space between elements are almost equal) inside extended array not just extend array.

Comment: Recently I have faced similar issue where I needed a method that does what you have described: performs as `zip` but works well with arrays of unequal size and I ended up writing a [gem that does that](https://rubygems.org/gems/distributed_merge). I will appreciate any contributions or ideas on how to improve it :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would use a sort to do this, based on element index postion, divided by size of array, plus some offset based on array id, to keep things consistent (if you don't need consistency, you could use a small random offset instead).

```
a = [:a,:b]
b = [:c]
c = [:d,:e,:f]
d = [:g:,:h,:i,:j]

def sort_pos array, id
  (1..array.size).map { |i| (i - 0.5 + id/1000.0)/(array.size + 1e-6) }
end

# Combine all the arrays with their sort index, assigning ids to each array for consistency.
# Depending on how you receive these arrays, this structure can be built up programatically, 
# as long as you add an array plus its sort index numbers at the same time
combined = (a + b + c + d).zip( sort_pos(a, 1) +  sort_pos(b, 2) +  sort_pos(c, 3) +  sort_pos(d, 4) )


# Extract the values from the original arrays in their new order
combined.sort_by { |zipped| zipped[1] }.map { |zipped| zipped[0] }

=> [:g, :d, :a, :h, :e, :i, :b, :f, :j, :c]
```

There might be a cleaner way of doing this in Ruby . . . but I think the end result is what you are after - an "even" mix of multiple arrays.

If you only care about even-ness of mix from a statistical perspective (i.e. over time it is "fair"), you could just do this:

```
(a+b+c+d).shuffle

=> [:g, :b, :i, :c, :a, :h, :e, :j, :f, :d]
```

Comment: Thanks, I just checked and it really works. At first seemed kinda complicated solution, but actually isn't. I'll wait few days before accepting let's see if someone finds another solution :)

And I can't use shuffle, because each time it randomly distributes elements and order isn't logical anymore.

Comment: actually seems it also works with just


    def sort_pos array
      (1..array.size).map { |i| (i - 0.5)/array.size }
    end

Comment: hate that can't show code properly in comments. anyway I created gist https://gist.github.com/davispuh/5246323 why exactly that `id` magic? without them seems to work just fine :)

Comment: The "id" should really be called "offset", and is just to provide control over ties in the sort. It's probably over-engineering and not needed by you - you can safely remove the id param if you are happy with Ruby's default sorting, which I think should preserve original order when there are ties, per item (e.g. if you add two 4-element arrays, each item from the second one you add will appear straight after each item from the first one)